# Query to find active records on a given date in a table recording "start" and "stop" dates

Tags: mysql, sql, temporal-database

I have a list of "start / stop" activity logged in a table, each one associated with a date. I need to determine which users had "started" on a particular date - i.e. were in progress with the task. My current setup and query can be represented by this simplistic view of it:

```
CREATE TABLE `registration_statuses` (
    `status_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `status_user_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `status_activity` ENUM('start','stop') DEFAULT 'start',
    `status_date` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`status_id`),
    INDEX `status_user_id` (`status_user_id`)
);

INSERT INTO `registration_statuses` (`status_user_id`, `status_activity`, `status_date`)
VALUES (1, 'start', '2020-01-01'),
       (2, 'start', '2020-01-02'),
       (1, 'stop', '2020-01-19'),
       (1, 'start', '2020-01-25'),
       (2, 'stop', '2020-01-31'),
       (1, 'stop', '2020-01-31');
```

I am then running this query:

```
SELECT `rs`.`status_user_id`
FROM `registration_statuses` `rs`
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT `status_user_id`, MAX(status_date) `last_date`
    FROM `registration_statuses`
    WHERE `status_date` < '2020-01-03'
    GROUP BY `status_user_id`
  ) `srs` ON `rs`.`status_user_id` = `srs`.`status_user_id`
            AND `rs`.`status_date` = `srs`.`last_date`
WHERE `status_activity` = 'start';
```

(See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c8d371/1/0)

By changing the date in the query, this query returns a list of user ids that tell me who is engaged (i.e. has started a task) on that specific date. However, the users are considered (in real life) to have been engaged with the task on the actual date that they stop it. This query doesn't allow for this in that if you were to change the date in the query to reflect 2020-01-19, the day on which user 1 stopped, the query would only return user 2.

I tried changing the `<=` condition to a strict `<`, and while this solves that part of the problem, users are not considered busy on the day that they start. With a strict `<`, only user is returned on '2019-01-25' whereas I want both users to appear.

My only "viable" solution, at this point, is to merge the results of the two versions of the queries (in the form of a `DISTINCT` / `UNION` query), but I can't help but think that there must be a more efficient way of obtaining the results I need.

Comment: Good work so far, but when providing a sample data set, it's usually helpful to include data that would be excluded from the desired result. And, to clarify, I think you want users who were engaged with a task through 2020-01-19?

Comment: @Strawberry Hi - I think I have... If you have a look on 20 Jan, for example, user 1 should be excluded. Have I misunderstood you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?

```
SELECT a.status_id
     , a.status_user_id 
     , a.status_date start
     , MIN(b.status_date) stop
  FROM registration_statuses a
  LEFT
  JOIN registration_statuses b
    ON b.status_user_id = a.status_user_id
   AND b.status_id > a.status_id
   AND b.status_activity = 'stop'
 WHERE a.status_activity = 'start'
 GROUP 
    BY a.status_id;

+-----------+----------------+------------+------------+
| status_id | status_user_id | start      | stop       |
+-----------+----------------+------------+------------+
|         1 |              1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-19 |
|         2 |              2 | 2020-01-02 | 2020-01-31 |
|         4 |              1 | 2020-01-25 | 2020-01-31 |
+-----------+----------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Yes, I think this will help. From here I can use a where condition to check against the start and stop dates, allowing it to include the stop date. The only question left to answer is regarding its performance, but that is easily tested.

Comment: Just another expression of appreciation: this has provided a great start. I modified your query to also include the activity status (since in reality we have more than just "start" and "stop"). This allows a good base from which to further filter. The query also seems to run well with hundreds of thousands of records.

Answer (score 0):

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
select rs.*
from registration_statuses rs
where rs.status_date = (select max(rs2.status_date)
                        from registration_statuses rs2
                        where rs2.status_user_id = rs.status_user_id and
                              rs2.status_date <= ?
                       ) and
      rs.status_activity = 'active';
```

For performance, you want an index on `registration_statuses(status_user_id, status_date)`.

There are other interesting methods.  If you just want the `user_id`, here is an approach only using aggregation:

```
select rs.user_id
from registration_statuses rs
where rs.status_date <= ?
group by rs.user_id
having max(rs.status_date) = max(case when rs.status_activity = 'active' then status_date end);
```

That is, select users whose most recent status date as of a particular date is "active".

Comment: Thanks for your attempts, but these are not helpful. The first query does not return user 1 on '2019-01-19' and as such is not suitable. The field names in your second query are broken, specifically, what do you mean by `status_end`?

Comment: @Philip . . . That user stopped on 2019-01-19, it would not seem to be active.  But, you can easily include it by changing the `<=` to `<` in the first query.  With the specified index, it should be faster than an aggregation query.